# What causes XOR encryption to return a "blank"?

Tags: encryption, c

What is the cause of certain characters to be blank when using XOR encryption? Furthermore, how can this be compensated for when decrypting?

For instance:

```
....
void basic_encrypt(char *to_encrypt) {
    char c;
    while (*to_encrypt) {
        *to_encrypt = *to_encrypt ^ 20;
        to_encrypt++;
    }
}
```

will return "nothing" for the character `k`. Clearly, character decay is problematic for decryption.

I assume this is caused by the bit operator, but I am not very good with binary so I was wondering if anyone could explain.

Is it converting an element, `k`, in this case, to some spaceless ASCII character? Can this be compensated for by choosing some y < x < z operator where x is the operator?

Lastly, if it hasn't been compensated for, is there a realistic decryption strategy for filling in blanks besides guess and check?

Comment: The ASCII value for 'k' is 0x6B, or 01101011. 01101011 ^ 00010100 is 01111111, which is not "nothing". What do you mean by "blank"?

Comment: It's a control code, so it will normally not be displayed.

Comment: @David. Thanks for showing the binary! Yeah, I figured it was something! Thus the quotes. I am still curious how to compensate for this, if one passes the array as plaintext rather than the variable, in particular.

Comment: @David by blank I mean that within the terminal I see no symbol when I print the encryption.

Comment: This is only a problem if you want the encrypted text to be viewable. Is that the case?

Comment: @FredLarson It is also a problem for passing the encryption between environments, is it not? Or is there a way around that problem?

Comment: @FredLarson And, if I do want the text viewable it seems to be quite a problem...!

Comment: By the way, this is NOT encryption.  It is a little bit of obfuscation.  For real encryption you could look up things like XXTEA or RSA.  Generally these protocols work with binary data and you can't expect all the bytes to be dispalyable ASCII characters.  You can inspect the bytes by printing their hex representations.

Comment: @d0rmLife: It may or may not be a problem for passing between environments, depending on how it is passed. Some protocols don't like control characters.

Comment: @d0rmLife - it seems to me that if you're doing something to obscure text, it shouldn't be surprising that it's obscured afterward. Typically, if obscured (or encrypted) data needs to stay readable (or printable, more typically), it is run through an additional base64 encoding.

Comment: @David Your point is taken, but it can be convenient for it remain printable, as you noted. The solution for this is to cast the elements as a different type, evidently.

Comment: Some kind of accept would be nice...

Comment: @owlstead It will be had. Difficult for me to choose between practical and theoretical.

Comment: @d0rmLife no problems there, vote ups are working well too, as long as you accept either one, otherwise the question remains open :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`'k'` has the ASCII value `107 = 0x6B`. `20` is `0x14`, so

```
'k' ^ 20 == 0x7F == 127
```

if your character set is ASCII compatible. `127` is `\DEL` in ASCII, which is a non-printable character, so won't be displayed if you print it out.

Comment: Great explanation! So, with this observation in mind, the variable `to_encrypt`, in this case, will retain that information; BUT, the message couldn't be passed as plaintext, is that right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "the message couldn't be passed as plaintext". If you XOR-encrypt a message, the encrypted message will usually contain some non-printable characters. So you can't print it out and read it back in somewhere else to decrypt it and get the original back, the characters that were encrypted as non-printable characters will be lost. But you can print out e.g. the hex representations of the characters. Those can be parsed back and decrypted without loss. Or you can send the stream of bytes (needs a length, since some characters are encrypted to 0) as bytes.

Comment: Or just send it as a 0x20-terminated string instead of a null-terminated string :)

Comment: @DavidGrayson Hmm, please don't make jokes like that on a question/answer that is for people just coming to understand character encoding :) Could you remove it?

Comment: It's not really a joke, just a slightly odd but good suggestion.  Looking for the 20 in a byte stream is a valid way to find the end of the "encrypted" string because the plaintext string was null-terminated.  (Oops, I wrote 0x20 in my first comment but I meant 20.)

Comment: In order to transmit the XOR "encrypted" (dramatic air quotes) as plain-text you should base64 encode the binary data.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to know the difference between bytes and characters to understand which is happening. On the one hand you have the C `char` type, which is simply a presentation of a byte, not a character.

In the old days each character was mapped to one byte or octet value in a character encoding table, or code page. Nowadays we have encodings that take more bytes for certain characters, e.g. UTF-8, or even encodings that always take more than one byte such as UTF-16. The last two are unicode encodings, which means that each character has a certain number value and the encoding is used to encode this number into bytes.

Many computers will interpret bytes in ISO/IEC 8859-1 or Latin-1, sometimes extended by Windows-1252. These code pages have holes for control characters, or byte values that are simply not used. Now it depends on the runtime system how these values are handled. Java by default substitutes an `?` character in place of the missing character. Other runtimes will simply drop the value or - of course - execute the control code. Some terminals may use the ESC control code to set the color or to switch to another code page (making a mess of the screen).

This is why ciphertext should be converted to another encoding, such as hexadecimals or Base64. These encodings should make sure that the result is readable text. This takes care of the cipher text. You will have to choose a character set for your plain text too, e.g. simply perform ASCII or UTF-8 encoding before encryption.

Comment: That *must* have been the quickest upvote I've ever received :)

Comment: Thanks for that level of detail.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a zero value from encryption does not matter because once you re-xor with the same xor key you get the original value.

```
value == value
value XOR value == 0 [encryption]
( value XOR value ) XOR value == value [decryption]
```

If you're using a zero-terminated string mechanism, then you have two main strategies for preventing 'character degradation'

- store the length of the string before encryption and make sure to decrypt at least that number of characters on decryption
- check for a zero character *after* decoding the character

Comment: But, if the value is passed as plaintext rather than as a variable the problem remains. Is there a way to compensate for this if one is passing the encryption beyond the confines of the environment where it was created?

Comment: You need to transmit bytes after encryption, not characters. If you send bytes, you must transmit all the encrypted characters, and if you don't send the length, and additional *encrypted* null character that will be checked on the decryption side (this is based on the encryption strategies I outlined)

Comment: Fundamentally, though, the end product of the encrypt routine is *no longer a string* per-se, but a byte array. You can keep passing the pointer around, but relying on code such as `strlen` will no longer work. You can decrypt using the second point of my strategies. If you want to transmit the data, then you have to make sure to transmit up to the length of the data, not the `strlen` of the data.